# NodeJS callback in a for-loop value is the same

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I was cleaning up my code and ran into a little trouble with callbacks, specifically getting the correct values to output when a callback is called. Could some **explain** to me why the following code spits out something that I'm not expecting and a possible solution without having to put in another parameter of i to the run() function, or is passing in i to know my index upon calling the callback the only way to do this?

```
for (var i in dls) {
    run(dls[i][0], dls[i][1], function(isTrue){
        if (isTrue) {
            // Do true stuff here
        } else {
            console.log("Value is: " + dls[i][3])
        }
    });
}
```

Calling run() actually has the correct inputs inside, but upon that function calling the callback and going into the else statement, dls[i][3] spits out the same value i times.

I've tried putting different scopes around (run()) and such but to no avail and can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

If I wanted to split it up into a separate function, how would I do it?

```
var run = function(cb){
    setTimeout(function() {
        cb(false)
    }, 3000);
}

for (var i in dls) {
    run(dls[i][0], dls[i][1], (function(index) {
        return extraction
    })(i));
}

function extraction(isTrue){
    if (isTrue) {
        // stuff
    } else {
        console.log("Nothing changed in " + dls[i][3])
    }
}
```

Here dls[i][3] is still incorrect and prints the same value 3 times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [understanding the concept of javascript callbacks with node.js, especially in loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506240/understanding-the-concept-of-javascript-callbacks-with-node-js-especially-in-lo)

Comment: I've looked at that thread and still couldn't find a potential solution to it, hence why I asked, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have fallen into the traditional "loop trap"

When it comes time for your callback to run `i` is now a different value.

What you can do is cache that value in another wrapper function:

```
for (var i in dls) {
    run(dls[i][0], dls[i][1], (function (currentIndex) { 
        return function(isTrue){
            if (isTrue) {
                // Do true stuff here
            } else {
                console.log("Value is: " + dls[currentIndex][3])
            }
        };
    })(i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Okay, a follow up to this. Let's say I don't want to create a new function every iteration. 

function extraction(isTrue){
console.log(dls[i][3])
}

for (var i in dls) {
 run(dls[i][0], dls[i][1], (function(index) {
  return extraction
 })(i));
}

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Because your callbacks happen at a later time when `i` is already set as a different value.

Comment: Hmm, how would I pass the cached value into the function without having to pass it in via the callback? Or would I have to now?

Comment: @Bryan you can just do as what is in my answer :-)

Comment: I'll play around with it since I sort of have an understanding. Just one last question, what does the (i) at the end of the run(.....)(i) function do?

Comment: I was trying to figure out what to do if I wanted to separate the function(isTrue){....}; and make that an external function. I don't seem to be in the scope for currentIndex anymore if I were to make the function outside of the for loop and seem to still run into the same repeated value problem.

Comment: The `i` at the end of the function is actually an argument inside of the function invocation. Since the value of `i` is passed to the function, instead of just referencing the original `i` inside the internal callback, it will be the value as you expect. You could also look into using `let` in ES6, which would solve the issue without requiring an IIFE. More reading [here](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Comment: Very helpful and useful read, thanks @dvlsg, learned something new today!

Comment: @dvlsg Do you think you can help me on the edited question above?

Comment: Sure - there are actually a couple of issues. `extraction` is never passed the correctly scoped `i`. `run` also is being called with 3 arguments, but the function only accepts one `cb` argument. I'll paste an answer in regards to the second question.

Comment: Actually, I may need more information to answer that second question properly, come to think of it. There are some errors as well -- for example, `extraction` tries to use the variable `i`, which is *sort of* in scope, but I think it's accidentally in scope. What you'll want to do is make a wrapper function around `extraction`. The wrapper should accept on argument `i`, then return the `extraction` function (just a reference to it, don't actually execute it) which makes use of the `i` from the argument, not the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the edit / second question, assuming this is what you wanted to do:

```
// note that I changed the function signature of `run`
var run = function(val1, val2, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        cb(false);
    }, 3000);
};

// note the `wrapper` here
for (var i in dls) {
    run(dls[i][0], dls[i][1], wrapper(i));
}

// this is the same as what the IIFE is doing,
// just with an external function instead
function wrapper(scopedIndex) {

    // return a function to be used as the callback for `run`
    return function extraction(isTrue) {
        if (isTrue) {
            // stuff
        }
        else {
            // use the scoped index here
            console.log("Nothing changed in " + dls[scopedIndex][3]);
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at `function makeExitCallback(i)` in the other [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506240/understanding-the-concept-of-javascript-callbacks-with-node-js-especially-in-lo), as well. It directly relates to what's going on here.

You should post what's in `dls` as well, just to make it easier to run your snippets locally.

Comment: I wrote something similar to this that worked! I found that the reason why I'm had so much trouble was because I didn't really and truly understand the concept of IIFE. I read this http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/ and it was pretty helpful telling me what each component was. Thanks dvlsg for the pointer. :-)

Comment: Yup, IIFE's always seem to take newer JS devs by surprise. They sure confused me the first time I saw one. Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: Thanks again. A little bit of practice and I might be able to teach someone else, haha. I wasn't sure exactly what to search regarding this question but looks like 6 hours and a helpful guide was all I needed to find about IIFE.